# Null Pointer Exception at com.examples.AddAppointment.addEvent(AddAppointment.java:125)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

i am getting this error null pointer exception. 
Little background
I have a main class, add appointment class and appointmentdata class.
appointmentData class has a method which creates database (SQLite) if not existing. AddAppointment Class gets values from a view with couple editText and user inserts some values and this data should be passed to method addEvent in the same class where the values are inserted to database, earlier created in appointmentData class. however the appointment Data class is never called hence the database is never created and as a result i get null pointer exception (values can not be inserted into db). 
Now my questions is. How do i call the class appointmentData in main class so the method onCreate is called and database is created.
Code below
AppointmetData class

```
 public class AppointmentsData extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "appointments.dba";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private String TIME;
    private String DESCRIPTION;
    private String DETAILS;
    private String DATE;

    //create helper object for events database
    public AppointmentsData(Context ctx){
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
                + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL" 
                + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL"
                + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL");
    }
       }
```

AddAppointment Class

```
public class AddAppointment extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private AppointmentsData events;
    private EditText appDesctription;
    private EditText appDate;
    private EditText appTime;
    private EditText appDetails;
    SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    //Connection conn; //A connection (session) with a specific database
    ResultSet rs; //A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries the database.
    PreparedStatement pst; //An ob
    String TableName = "appointments";


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.appointment_details);

        appDate = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.appDate);

        appDate.setKeyListener(null);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras !=null) {
            String dateSelected = extras.getString("dateselected");
            appDate.setText(dateSelected);

            View saveAppointment = findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
            saveAppointment.setOnClickListener(this);

            //SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();




        }

    }
    private String DESCRIPTION;
    private String DATE;
    private String TIME;
    private String DETAILS;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            appDesctription = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.appDescription);
            DESCRIPTION = appDesctription.getText().toString();

            appTime = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.appTime);
            TIME = appTime.getText().toString();

            appDetails = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.appDetails);
            DETAILS = appDetails.getText().toString();

            DATE = appDate.getText().toString();

            AddAppointment aa = new AddAppointment();
            aa.addEvent(DESCRIPTION);
            aa.addEvent(DATE);
            aa.addEvent(DETAILS);
            aa.addEvent(TIME);

            Intent j = new Intent(this, CalendarViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(j);

    }


            private void addEvent(String string) {
                //insert a new record into Events data source
                //would do something similar for delete and update
                SQLiteDatabase db = events.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                // add key and value
                values.put(DESCRIPTION, string);
                values.put(DATE, string);
                values.put(TIME, string);
                values.put(DETAILS, string);
                db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            }
            private String[] FROM = { _ID, TIME, DESCRIPTION, };
            private static String ORDER_BY = _ID + "DESC";
            private Cursor getEvents(){
                //perform managed query. The activity will handle closing
                //and requerying the cursor when needed
                SQLiteDatabase db = events.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, FROM ,null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                return cursor;              


    }

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have incorrect `DML` statement in your `onCreate()` method in SQLiteOpenHelper subclass.

Here:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
                + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL" 
                + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL"
                + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL"
```

you are missing commas behind date and description column and last right parenthesis at the end of statement. This is reason why your database is never created. Try to fix it and it should works.

So here is corrected statement:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                    + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
                    + DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL," 
                    + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                    + DETAILS + " TEXT NOT NULL)"
```

Comment: It still didn't solve the problem. but i have scrapped the whole code and wrote it again. This time in a much more efficient manner. I just create Database handler class (taking care of all CRUID) Appointment Class (set and get methods) and now i will just call appropriate CRUID wherever i want in other classes :). I think this approach is much better then the one in original question